# Scrolling the content of an HTML element, rather than the whole window object

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have the following two in my hands:

```
#elementA {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(100,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,250,0.3));
    z-index: 250;
}

#containerofA {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 240;
    padding-bottom: 100px;  // to hide the horizontal scrollbar
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The `elementA` as a `div` appears inside the `containerofA` as a `div` again. `elementA` has twice the width as its container, and is to be scrolled with a touch-capable device.

These things already happen. What I'm after is to have the `elementA` to be initially scrolled to middle. I want it to be either positioned at `-50%` initially, or to be scrolled towards right by `50%` upon loading.

In JavaScript, CSS or HTML: How to do that?

`window.scroll(offset-x, offset-y);` and variations scroll the whole window, if they can. It should really be an easy thing to do, but I cannot see how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft) property of dom elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCN7n/

```
document.getElementById('containerofA').scrollLeft = 250;
```

Comment: Thanks for the first complete and flawless answer, also hinting that I should apply the property to the container. Not to disdain the others, but it feels more right to pick the complete answer as the answer, although it has been given the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $(element).scrollLeft(offset-left);
});
```

Comment: The `$` thing is probably of jSomething, but yeah, this works out, just like the first answer.

Comment: It's jQuery. Sabitpockers' answer is better if you use plain javascript.

Comment: From description of Javascript Tag - "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) and [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft) properties.

Comment: This is correct, except that I wanted to have horizontal scrolling, not vertical. Nevertheless, it is correct.

Comment: Sorry I have modified the answer to include the property that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like:

```
.Container{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.Elementcontained{
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;
width:200%;
height:100%;
}
```

That should probably work?